# How do I get the substring of a JSON output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, sinatra, padrino

I want to render a simple JSON from an array.

```
array = ["valueid",true]
render :json=>array
```

which returns:

```
{"json":["valueid",true]}
```

but I don't want the JSON. The only part I want is:

```
["valueid",true]
```

Is there a simple way?

Comment: header must be json type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep:

```
get :index do
  [:id, 4].to_json
end
```

Better:

```
get :index, :provides => :json do
   my_array.to_json
end
```